# PHP array formatting?

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried to convert

```
$user = array();

$user[] = array("name" => "Jesse James", "email" => "jesse@example.com", "phone" => "212-999-9999");
$user[] = array("name" => "Donald Duck", "email" => "donals@example.com", "phone" => "818-999-9999");
```

### OUTPUT

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Jesse James [email] => jesse@example.com [phone] => 212-999-9999 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Donald Duck [email] => donals@example.com [phone] => 818-999-9999 ) )
```

---

but I want to convert it to:

```
Array ( [name[0]] => Jesse James [email[0]] => jesse@example.com [phone[0]] => 212-999-9999 ) [1] => Array ( [name[1]] => Donald Duck [email[1]] => donals@example.com [phone[1]] => 818-999-9999 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, for the future format your code before posting.

```
$a = array(
  "name" => "Jesse James",
  "email" => "jesse@example.com",
  "phone" => "212-999-9999"
);

$b = array(
  "name" => "Donald Duck",
  "email" => "donals@example.com",
  "phone" => "818-999-9999"
);

print_r(array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jesse James
            [1] => Donald Duck
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => jesse@example.com
            [1] => donals@example.com
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 212-999-9999
            [1] => 818-999-9999
        )

)
```